# SVG to PDF (with Perl Cairo?)

Tags: perl, pdf, svg, cairo, strawberry-perl

In a perl script, I try to convert svg files to pdf. This works great by just refering to Inkscape:

```
system "inkscape -D -z --file=$in --export-pdf=$out";
```

But it is enormously slow even for little 100 KB files, I mean it can be minutes per file, causing the script to fail when running with a time-out constrain, eg. on a webserver.

To speed up, I have read about `svg2pdf` as a standalone, but never found a binary for Win7 or managed to compile it, even with the libcairo dlls present.

My last idea now is to use the CPAN module `Cairo`. It makes me hoping that it can convert an svg file to pdf, but in the documentation I only find drawings and surfaces, but no method to write/convert.
Has anyone experience with that?

Comment: `rsvg-convert` is probably faster than Inkscape but it's still an external command.

Comment: Yes, nwellnhof, thanks for the tip! `rsvg-convert.exe -f pdf -o out.pdf in.svg` is takes 0.5sec for what inkscape needs 10-20sec. It is just one binary for windows and so easy to port. Link: http://opensourcepack.blogspot.de/2012/06/rsvg-convert-svg-image-conversion-tool.html Please post an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment an answer: You could try `rsvg-convert` which is part of the *librsvg* library. It's probably faster than Inkscape but it's still an external command.